# PyCharm unresolved reference when importing all modules from folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I am trying to make pycharm to resolve reference to module when importing all modules from folder

[image: screenshot]

The code in the screenshot works fine but Pycharm cannot see `businessnetworkcouk` (or any other module in the folder `projectsites`) and complains about unresolved reference.

I've already tried

- marking `projectsites` folder as source root
- invalidate caches
- restarting pycharm

If I import `businessnetworkcouk` module with

```
from projectsites import businessnetworkcouk
```

Pycharm recognises it well

Answer (score 0):

You can add the folder with your imports to your project structure. This way PyCharm will recognize your files.

It can be done under
**Preferences | Project:foo | Project Structure**

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why this could be happening. Below are several steps that fixes the majority of those cases:

**.idea caching issue**

Some `.idea` issue causing the IDE to show error while the code still runs correctly. Solution:

1. close the project and quick PyCharm
2. delete the `.idea` folder where the project is. note that it is a hidden folder and you might not be aware of its existence in your project directory.
3. start PyCharm and recreate the project

**imports relative not to project folder**

Relative imports while code root folder is not the same as the project folder. Solution:

1. Find the folder that relative imports require in the project explorer
2. right click and mark it as "Source Root"

**Editor not marking **init**.py as Python**

Which is the most illusive of all the cases. Here, for some reason, PyCharm considers all `__init__.py` files not to be python files, and thus ignores them during code analysis. To fix this:

1. Open PyCharm settings
2. Navigate to Editor -> File Types
3. Find Python and add `__init__.py` to the list of python files or find Text and delete `__init__.py` from the list of text files